# Nested Typescript Map Type

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types

With Typescript 4.5.0, I can't seem to get the type of values to compile. For the following:

```
type foo = 'a' | 'b'

const x: Map<foo, {[key: string]: string}> = new Map([
  ['a', {'ok': 'so'}],
  ['b', {'nah': 'right'}]
])
```

tsc barfs up

```
const x: Map<foo, {
    [key: string]: string;
}>
Type 'Map<"a" | "b", { 'ok': string; 'nah'?: undefined; } | { 'nah': string; 'ok'?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'Map<foo, { [key: string]: string; }>'.
  Type '{ 'ok': string; 'nah'?: undefined; } | { 'nah': string; 'ok'?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
    Type '{ 'ok': string; 'nah'?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
      Property ''nah'' is incompatible with index signature.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Is this a compiler bug, or am I doing something wrong to make the Map's value generic look like a union type?

[A link to the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nKBeKByAhqqAfNAjVAKEIGM4A7AZ2CgA8AuKAWXTAB544AaKAbwG0A1hBCNqAJwCW5AOYBdMcCmyAvgD5kUchADuzVgAp+hKFH4ZUPXqjiDUjVJTioVcribOoCV1OXQALezQpGX9gFzlCOQBKIA)

Comment: Index signatures and `undefined` values are a little weird... in this case I'd say that you should either use the type `{[key: string]: string | undefined}` or try `new Map<foo, {[k: string]: string]}>`... but I'm wondering what your use case is.  I usually use the `{[k: string]: SomeType | undefined}` since it is unlikely that every possible key has a value

Comment: And as far as I know this would have been a bug all the way back to TS2.7 when [types unions of object literal types were improved](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals).

Comment: If you can expand on your use case (how exactly do you plan to read from / write to this map? )  I can turn these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is not a bug. Typescript narrows the type of your right side down to `{ok: string, nah?: undefined} | {ok?: undefined, nah: string}`, since you have two objects that are missing the property of the other. The one that has only "ok" will return undefined if "nah" is accessed and vice-versa.

This means that the initial type `{[key: string]: string}` is not valid anymore, because the properties can either return a string ('so' and 'right' are subtypes of string) or undefined.

The simpliest way around this is to allow these undefined values by using `Map<foo, {[key: string]: string | undefined}>`.

**Edit:** Corrected the inferred type - thanks to jcalz for pointing that out!

Comment: It's not narrowing to `{ok?: "so", nah?: "right"}`.  It's being inferred as `{ok: string, nah?: undefined} | {ok?: undefined, nah: string}`, which is a different type.

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript's type inference can be a bit confusing sometimes. It is never perfect and the TypeScript team had to make hard choices.
You get one of these choices that does not match your expectations...

You can get ride of type inference by explicitly specifying the generic types:

```
const x = new Map<foo, {[key: string]: string}>([
  ['a', {'ok': 'so'}],
  ['b', {'nah': 'right'}]
])
```