# Nested Typescript Map Value Type

Tags: typescript

Similar to [Nested Typescript Map Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128823/nested-typescript-map-type) but the nesting is on the "value" side.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4HkBGArApsK7u4BcMAssgDzQBOAlmAOYA0M1d9MAPqRaw87-QB8gmAF4YYLAHduSABT4cUAHRYwUWlghyA3gCgYhmACIEx4sbTHGBo8eDmJ02QsxLV6zdv1HfJgCaOxljWtoYAvgCUkXpRkQDcenqgkLCIqG64ZEjE2ZQabPwFDJyy+bR8LMVCIuKSMtmuBCpqBVq6YSZmFlY2vvaO9S4A2p2+w8aBzMHGALqdszFxicng0PDI2YpEZQJFFexceXtVB8JiTg3IcqPjptYmVrN9RhMOzEON2y2eNO0+fkMkyCIReEWiekWK1WqQ2SGy2VyPGq+zYpWOKNObHOdWcjVur3u0yeYJgbwen2uBMBEymJhC818i3mUKAA)

```js
const mapObjectObject: Map<string, string | Map<string, string>> = new Map(Object.entries({
    "a": "b",
    "c": new Map(Object.entries({
        "d": "e",
    }))
})); // ✓

const mapObjectMap: Map<string, string | Map<string, string>> = new Map(Object.entries({
    "a": "b",
    "c": new Map([
        ["d", "e"]
    ])
})); // ✓

const mapMapObject: Map<string, string | Map<string, string>> = new Map([
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", new Map(Object.entries({
        "d": "e",
    }))
]); // ✗


const mapMapMap: Map<string, string | Map<string, string>> = new Map([
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", new Map([
        ["d", "e"]
    ])]
]); // ✗
```

Why do the first two work, but the second two don't. They both error with:

```
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, string]>): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, string]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<[string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [string, string], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [string, string], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [string, string]>'.
              Type '[string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.
                Type '[string, Map<string, string>]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [string, string]'.
                  Types of property '1' are incompatible.
                    Type 'Map<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [string, string])[] | null | undefined): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Map<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2769)
```

and

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, string]>): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([string, string] | [string, Map<string, string>])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, string]>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [string, string])[] | null | undefined): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Map<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2769)
```

Respectively. Removing the type declaration doesn't help either. Inferred types also have the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give a hint to TS about types:

```
const mapMapObject = new Map<string, string | Map<string, string>>([
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", new Map(Object.entries({
        "d": "e",
    }))
]]);

const mapMapMap = new Map<string, string | Map<string, string>>([
    ["a", "b"],
    ["c", new Map([
        ["d", "e"]
    ])]
]);
```